# mysql and php insert multiple row of input field to database at once

Tags: php, mysql

i want to insert data from a form which is declared in while loop and can be iterated 40 times (mean 40 row with 6 input fields each row).so what i need,i need to insert data from every input field (currently 6) to mysql row .so how can i accomplish that.please ask me for further detail if you need.

looking forward for best answer.i am stuck here and it's my degree final year project.
thank you for help.

This is while loop with input fields code and name retrieved from database.

```
include'connection.php';
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `std_register` AS p1 ,`sims-register-course` AS p2 WHERE p2.semester=p1.std_semester and p2.department=p1.std_department and p2.id = '".$_GET['id']."'");
if ($res==FALSE) {
echo die(mysql_error());
    }
echo "<form method='POST' action= '".htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."'.'>'";
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row["std_name"].'</td>';
    echo "<td><input type='text' id='attendence_marks' name='attendence_marks[]' class='input-field-size'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' id='assignment_marks' name='assignment_marks[]' class='input-field-size'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' id='presentation_marks' name='presentation_marks[]' class='input-field-size'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' id='other_marks' name='other_marks[]' class='input-field-size'></td>";
    cho "<td><input type='text' id='mid_marks' name='mid_marks[]' class='input-field-size'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' id='final_marks' name='final_marks[]' class='input-field-size'></td>";
    }
```

I want to insert data from this form to database with single button click after fields are filled.and input all the rows of form into database at once.

This is the loop i have used to insert data but not working and display me some errors also.previously i have used for loop but that was also not working correctly.and insert only 0's to database.please checkout the loop code here and i think i am doing it wrong so please make me correct.

```
<?php
    $count = count($_POST);
    echo "count is :".$count ."<br>";
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $attendence_marks=$_POST['attendence_marks'];
    $assignment_marks=$_POST['assignment_marks'];
    $presentation_marks=$_POST['presentation_marks'];
    $other_marks=$_POST['other_marks'];
    $mid_marks=$_POST['mid_marks'];
    $final_marks=$_POST['final_marks'];
    $total_marks = $attendence_marks+$assignment_marks+$presentation_marks+$other_marks+$mid_marks+$final_marks;
    foreach ($attendence_marks as $key1 => $att_marks) {
    foreach ($assignment_marks as $key2 => $assig_marks) {
    foreach ($presentation_marks as $key3 => $pre_marks) {
    foreach ($other_marks as $key4 => $o_marks) {
    foreach ($mid_marks as $key5 => $m_marks) {
    foreach ($final_marks as $key6 => $f_marks) {
    foreach ($total_marks as $key7 => $t_marks) {
    $i = "INSERT INTO `std_gradding` (attendence_marks,assignment_marks,presentation_marks,other_marks,mid_term_marks,final_marks,total_marks) VALUES ('$att_marks','$assig_marks','$pre_marks','$o_marks','$m_marks','$f_marks','$t_marks')";
    $result = mysql_query($i) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "Data Inserted.Thank you.";
    echo "$assignment_marks , $presentation_marks , $other_marks , $mid_marks , $final_marks , $total_marks" ;


       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
}

}
?>
```

Comment: To which school are you going? I would quit immediatly if they teach you this sort of code.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? You don't know how to insert into the database, but you know how to select from one?

Comment: they didn't teach me code exactly this is my own idea of creating code.if you wana tune the code than please reply me with answer.thank you for your precious time.

Comment: @N.B. i know how to insert to database.but i don't know how to insert from array to a database.it only insert the first row to database and not more than that.

Comment: Do you know how to loop an array?

Comment: @N.B.
not actually.
checkout my form i have uploaded a photo with some students register and dynamically retrieved data.
this is how my form look.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24290985/database.png

and this is my database table.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24290985/database%202.png

Comment: I won't look at future "computer scientist's" form and provide copy paste solution. If you don't know what an array or loop are, google it and learn about it. I gave you a hit on looping an array, find out what it is.

Comment: @N.B.
actually i have done looping through my arrays.you can see in my form name section i have already created an array and input data through for loop but that didn't work for me.
the form insert wrong data (only 0's) to the database.
so at this point i stuck.and don't know where the error lies.
than i try foreach loop and that also not working.if you want to look at the code how i used that i can send you that in comments here?
thank you.

Comment: @N.B.
i have updated my post now you can look at the full code.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this example

```
<?php
echo '<form method="post" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">';
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    echo '<input name="text['.$i.']" value="input '.$i.'"><br>';
}
echo '<input type="submit"><br>';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

And the post dump is:

```
array (
  'text' => 
  array (
    0 => 'input 0',
    1 => 'input 1',
    2 => 'input 2',
    3 => 'input 3',
    4 => 'input 4',
  ),
)
```

Comment: i have tried loop but it insert only 0 values to all my database fields.and for two input rows they insert upto 100 rows in database.

Comment: did not get what you mean

Comment: i mean when i use loop in my code and press submit button.than it insert upto 100 rows into database table.without correct data.and these 100 rows are only for two rows of form.
if the form contain 40 rows than it become more heavy and show me timeout.so can you please send me full code that i may implement and give it a try and will let you know after a try :)

Comment: ID-s? where i missed some.
the input fields repeat 40 times if there are 40 students.
and if there are 40 students i want to insert all that 40 students data at once to database.checkout this image.this is how my form look like.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24290985/database.png

and this is my database table look.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24290985/database%202.png

Comment: if it is possible, please give the database structure and specify what and where is supposed to be inserted

Answer (score -1):

The first problem I see is that your id's are not unique. You could number them.

```
id='attendence_marks_1'
```

for the first row. Then you can actually access the values, and they will get properly posted when you submit the form. The rest is basis stuff.

Comment: can you please also reply me about the insert into database statement.and thank you for valuable time and reply.

Comment: What can I say? I see a lot of nested 'foreach' loops, that cannot be good. But since my answer is voted down, and it's an assignment afterall, I see no reason to continue.

Comment: you should have to help me..that's why i am here..if you don't and other also think like you than this is not good for any one or any reason.sometime help is more important than reputation,so please help me out.
thank you.

Comment: You're right, this site is for helping people. There's already enough help here to get your project started again (id's and the loops). Use it.

Comment: so you mean i use
    id='attendence_marks_1'
    id='assignment_marks_2'
and so on.
and is my for loop correct?
i think not because it doesn't insert data to database and show error also at top most line.
if i use for loop that will be appropriate and should work?
@KIKO Software

Comment: Yes, EACH id must be unique, that's a requirement of HTML/CSS. With the 'loops' I was referring to your many nested 'foreach' loops. That just looks a bit much. My advice would be to start with a simpler form and database insertion routine. Make sure that works. Only then make it more complex. It's not wise to start very complex and then not get it to work.